# What is the recommended way of specifying machineKey when hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service, machinekey

I'm trying to figure out what the is best way to set the MachineKey for a site when hosted in both an Azure Cloud Service Web role and an Azure Web site when using multiple servers.

There seems to be several proposed solution I can find, none seem right to me.

1. Use session affinity (on by default in Web sites)

   - While this may work, it feels like a work around. The reason one would choose to have multiple servers to for the purposed of fail-over, but this means clients with an affinity to the broken server cannot run against the other server, does that not somewhat defeat the object of fail-over?
2. Set the machineKey in a web.config transform

   - This requires the machine key to be stored under source control, which defeats the object of the encryption using the machine key.
3. Done have a dependency on the machine key, so you don't care.

   - It's very easy to miss a dependency because it's used unbeknownst to you within the internals of ASP.NET, and you may not know you have a problem because it's rarely used or you already have server affinity (on by default in Web sites)

I kind of feel I'm missing something, or maybe I'm suffering from [Analysis Paralysis](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnalysisParalysisOverthinkingAndKnowingTooMuchToJustCODE.aspx) and should just get on with it.

Comment: You can always encrypt the `machinekey` section in your `Web.config`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'd missed that one. By what means is the config encrypted/decrypted, I'd always assumed it was the machineKey.

Comment: You can protect your `Web.config` by introducing your own implementation of `System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider`. Yet, the common (and already built-in) implementation is the `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx).